# How to call Aggregation pipeline call from C# code

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can we create aggregation pipeline on mongo server and call from C# code with parameters, same as stored procedure in sql

I would like to create aggregation pipeline on mongo server and call it from c# code with some parameters.

Comment: look at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/ but it doesn't support providing options

Comment: @dododo is faster than I. This can't really be done today. You can create a [view](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/) which is essentially a stored aggregation pipeline, but there is currently no support for adding variables to them. You can, however, provide additional filtering when querying the view, though it's not clear if that will suffice for your use case.